# old response with DelegatingHandler, error 500

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send back as a response an old response, and this fails with a error 500 on browser side:

```
public class MyDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    [...]

    protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        [...]
        // I basically tried:
        var response = oldResponse;
        // I also trying :
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = oldResponse.Content
        };

        // response is sent back
        var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
                tsc.SetResult(response);   
                return tsc.Task;
    }
}
```

I also tried this basic example:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StringContent("Hello")
};
```

and this time it worked fine.

Is my approach wrong? Is there simply something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out the issue: The HttpResponseMessage and its Content is disposed once the it has been consumed. This is why it cannot been used twice.

So I tried to rebuild the HttpResponseMessage this way:

```
object contentValue = null;
// Should be surrounded with if to check whether extraction succeded of course :-)
cachedResponse.TryGetContentValue(out contentValue);
var response = request.CreateResponse(contentValue);
```

and it seems to work.

Thanks for those who took time to read the post.